# How to create file in the local fs using modern FileApi?

Tags: javascript, fileapi

I have this code:

```js
document.querySelector('#myfile').onchange = function(e) {
  var files = this.files;
  window.requestFileSystem(window.TEMPORARY, 1024 * 1024, function(fs) {
    let file = files[0];
    let nem_file_name = file.name + '_copy';
    fs.root.getFile(nem_file_name, {
      create: true,
      exclusive: true
    }, function(fileEntry) {
      fileEntry.createWriter(fileWriter => {
        fileWriter.write(file);
      }, () => alert('error 1'));
    }, err => alert('error 2 ' + err));
  }, () => alert('error 3'));
};
```

```html
<input type="file" id="myfile" ref="myfile" multiple />
```

I want to create a copy of my file when I select it with the input control. What's wrong with my code? I got no errors and nothing happens

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem of it failing silently. It provides a very clear and obvious error when I trigger that function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "*modern*" API is called [File System Access](https://wicg.github.io/file-system-access/), it is still only a proposal, but is expected to supersede the previous and deprecated *File System API*, and is already available in Chromium browsers.

To write a file using this API, you first request a FileHandle using the `showSaveFilePicker()` method, then you can create a writer from that handle and append data using that writer:

```js
onclick = async (e) => { // needs to be initiated by an user gesture
  const handle = await showSaveFilePicker(); // prompt "Save As"
  const writer = await handle.createWritable(); // request writable stream
  await writer.write( new Blob( [ "some data" ] ) ); // write the Blob directly
  writer.close(); // end writing
};
```

But this API is still overprotected, so it unfortunately can't be ran in cross-origin iframes like the ones used here by StackSnippet or most popular fiddling services. So in order to make a live demo, I had to [make a plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/s7QsIYDe0ghcndnf?open=lib%2Fscript.js), that **you must run in windowed mode**.

And if you need to set the name of the file yourself, you need to request for a directory access using `showDirectoryPicker()` and then to get a FileHandle from that directory handle using its `getFileHandle()` method. [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/6aXVTu23Ex7GfxIu?open=lib%2Fscript.js)

Comment: Does any solution exist to write a file locally at least in Chrome browser?

Comment: @mystdeim did you read this answer? Yes such a solution exists, the code in there does just that.

Comment: I add window. before showSaveFilePicker in your sample and it works, thanks!

Comment: btw, I didn't find possibility to pass a custom filename to showSaveFilePicker.

Comment: @mystdeim ... it's also in the answer, check the second plnkr

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/requestFileSystem) states that this method is non-standard, only in Chrome and already deprecated:

> Even compared to the rest of the File and Directory Entries API,
> requestFileSystem() is especially non-standard; only Chrome implements
> it, and all other browser makers have decided that they will not
> implement it. It has even been removed from the proposed
> specification. Do not use this method!

You should not use this.

Comment: actually, it's not a problem for me